# Can't filter strange Apostrophe from String

Tags: php, string

I'm parsing some stuff and encountert a strange apostrophe `’` and thats breaking my parsed string resultig in `├ó┬Ç┬Ö`

What I tried:

`htmlentities()`, `iconv()`, `utf8encode()`, `utf8_decode()`

my sanitize function , currently a bit messy and hulked up trying to get rid of that evildoer

```
  public function sanitizeName($name) {

    $valid = range('a', 'z');
    $valid = array_merge($valid, range('A','Z'));
    $valid = array_merge($valid, range(0,9));
    $valid = array_merge($valid, array('_',',','.','?','!',' ','-',':',';','#','+',     '"'));

    $name = trim($name);
    $name = str_replace(array('\\', '/','’', '`', '´'), '', $name);
    $name = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/', '', $name);
    $name = preg_replace('/\(.+\)/', '', $name);
    $name = utf8_decode($name);
    $valid_name = '';
    for($i = 0, $len = strlen($name); $i < $len; $i++) {
        if(in_array($name[$i], $valid)) {
            $valid_name .= $name[$i];
        }
    }
    if(stripos($valid_name, '├') !== false) { //that one isn't even triggering
        echo 'adsfg';die;                     //even though the character is there
    }
    $name = trim($valid_name);
    if(strlen($name) > 0) {
        return $name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Just a suggestions, you can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove characters too (by providing a `charlist`)

Comment: already tried doing a str_replace on it, it's even bypasses my `$valid` array

Comment: is it just me or does `├ó┬Ç┬Ö` remind you of [this movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1467304/)?